# Responsive website - Different image based on browser window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a responsive website using html5, css3 and jquery. I've got an idea that I'd really like to implement, but am stuggeling to find a way to do so. Any help would be much appreciated/voted up.

I'd like to display a particular image on my webpage **depending** on the current browser size. Then. I'd like that image to be replaced with a different image as soon as the browser window is resized by a few pixels e.g. dragging right window edge inwards. So in a way, it would *animate* a sequence of images based on the browser size.

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                    /
|                    \
|                    /   <---
|                    \ 
|                X   /   <---
|                    \
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ /

E.g. Page width: 940px

 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                  /
|                  \
|                  /   <---
|                  \ 
|              Y   /   <---
|                  \
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ /

E.g. Page width: 930px
```

In the above example, 'X' represents one image, 'Y' another image, and so on. So for example, for every 10 pixels the window is made smaller, a new image would appear in its place.

**THE QUESTION:**

What would be the best way to implement something like this, without using Flash? Is there a better way of doing such an 'animation based on page width'?

All comments are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: javascript might be your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS media queries and background images, eg

```
<div class="dynamic-image"></div>
```

and CSS

```
.dynamic-image {
    background: url(smallest-screen-size-image.png) ... ;
    /* and any other styles required, maybe even a nice transition */
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

@media (min-width: 930px) {
    .dynamic-image {
        background-image: url(Y.png);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 940px) {
    .dynamic-image {
        background-image: url(X.png);
    }
}

/* and so on */
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/gPtjz/

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the answer. I think it's the closest to what I'm looking for. I'd like to use many seperate images, I think around 60, would it be 'bad coding' to create seperate @media queries for each one?

Comment: @Alex You'd only have as many media queries as you'd have *stop points* (ie, screen widths). You can load as many styles into each `@media` block as you want. Whilst 60 seems a bit granular to me, it should work just fine

Comment: @Alex I've added a demo with some nice transitions so you can see what you can achieve via CSS alone

Comment: Thank you, that works really nicely. 

Sorry for so many (noob) questions. But, how would I make it responsive in a way that the image plays though its sequence on all screen sizes and not just the fixed width dimension in your example?

I've tried changing min-width to a (%) percentage based calculation, but that didn't work. How would I get it to fill up the whole screen, no matter how wide it is?

Answer (score 4):

With plain CSS3 You could try something like

```
@media all and (min-width: 1440x) {
  body {
   background: url(img1);
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1440px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background: url(img2);
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
   background: url(img3);
  }
}
```

it looks a little too verbose, but it's a start. I'd turn to bootstrap to use its responsive classes instead of doing it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the code. I'm currently using the 'Skeleton' grid. I'd like to have multiple images (small ones, perhaps in the bottom right corner). Would using, say, 60 seperate media queries plus 60 images to go with them be a possible solution? or is that just silly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link to an example](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/tm9Y6/1/) using jQuery/JavaScript in jsFiddle.

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(viewportWidth);
    $("#imageChanger").attr("src", viewportWidth + ".jpg");  
    $("#imageDescription").html(viewportWidth + ".jpg");  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imageDescription">The filename will appear here</div>
<div ><img id="imageChanger" src="1.jpg" width="900" height="300"></div>
```

Comment: Age Crystl That's awesome thanks! Is there a way to make it go up/down in steps? e.g. 10px++?

Comment: Sure, you could do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/tm9Y6/2/) but you would need to add some conditionals for back and forth / up and down.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant the image numbers that are fed in. At the moment there are as many images as there are pixels. I'd like it to pick up 1 image for every 10pixels that the browser is resized down to. So, 1.jpg would display at 990px width, 2.jpg at 980px width etc.

Comment: yep, that would be [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/tm9Y6/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use media queries.  With that said though it depends on how many images that you're thinking of using to determine what the best solution is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought of using media queries, but I'd like to use many images (perhaps around 60?) to produce a sort of animation.